# XCode force touch

Tags: xcode, touch

How can I force Xcode (4.5.x) to force "touch" on a file (foo.m) every time I hit the build button.

I would like that file to be compiled every time even though nothing has changed (It contains a **DATE** & **TIME** macro in case you are curious).

Answer (score 0):

That's a poor solution.  Better would be to run a build script that will generate a source file containing the current date and time.  You can then compile and link this generated source file with the final binary.

This will also make it easier to manage with `git`, as `foo.m` won't be seen to change even though no functional changes have occurred.

Comment: I like your solution - however I am not sure how I can generate a build script - I am a newbie - can you provide any pointers to start with

Comment: @OneGuyInDc OK, I'll get back to you on that, when I'm back in front of Xcode.